# Give me some info about REAPER

Tags: perl

I a perl code have seen the `REAPER` has used as a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` signal .

```
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
```

The function also not defined in the code . Can any one deeply explain the internal operation on the `REAPER` .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code that references REAPER?

Answer (score 2):

- **Read : [PerlIPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals)**-Perl interprocess communication (signals,
  fifos, pipes, safe subprocesses,
  sockets, and semaphores).
- **Read**: **"Reaping Zombies"** from Chapter 16.01 in "Perl Programming third Edition" by Larry
  Wall

Comment: That just shows how to write your own `REAPER` but the OP complains it isn't written in his code.

Comment: @Karthi: Both links will help you to understand how it is working. It might be possible it is used for Zombies but for that case also REAPER function should be there.

Comment: @Nikhil - please do not link to pirated copies of books (your second link)

Comment: I never realised that was a pirate site. naively I'd just assumed it was something to do with O'Reilly!

Comment: @Martin Smith: Exactly, I also never realised it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    All Our perls have run
    Here but now they're hung
    Children don't fear the reaper
    Nor Do the wind, the sun or the rain
    We can be like they are

    Come on process, Don't fear the Reaper
    Baby take My file, Don't fear the Reaper
    We'll be able to crash, Don't fear the Reaper
    Baby it's your code
```

`REAPER` is just a placeholder name for code you have to write yourself.  See [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for more details.

Comment: Your poem doesn't compile.  :-(

Comment: add `sub UNIVERSAL::AUTOLOAD {}` before it :-)